# program with 10 integers and the possibility to see the biggest/smallest integer and so on

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, integer

I'm really new to programming and I am just trying to learn Python since a few weeks back. I find it pretty hard but really fun also. I'm trying to do a program right now where the user insert 10 integers, and then gets the possibility to do the following:

program: "What would you like to do?:"
1. Show me the biggest integer.
2. Show me the smallest integer.
3. Show me the average of all numbers combined with one decimal.
4. Show me all the entered integers.
5. Terminate this program.

```
nr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=int(input("Please Enter an integer. "))
    nr.append(a)
    s = [max(nr), min(nr), nr, sum(nr)/len(nr)]
    z = int((input("Please enter a number between 1 to 4. ")))
    if z == 1:
        print(s[0])
    elif z== 2:
        print(s[0])
    elif z == 3:
        print(s[0])
    elif z == 4:
        print(s[0])
    elif z == 5:
        break
    else:
        print("Please select a number between 1 to 5.")
```

This is how far I've come, and now I'm just stuck. When I get the "Please enter an Integer" I enter, let's say for example "1". Then I get the "Please enter a number between 1 to 4" directly after that. Can someone please help me where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: Python has built-in `min`, `max` and `sum` functions. This should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I can give you a hint: [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html). Especially `print`, `min`, `max`, `sum`, `len` and `round` should be interesting

Comment: You never tried to  find atleast using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to write your code for you, but here I have some hints for you:

> To find the maximum or the minimum in a set of integers, you can iterate through the set, save the first number to a variable outside the loop and compare the next number to it.

If the number is smaller or bigger (depending on what you are looking for, min or max) you set the variable to the new value.

After you iterated through the set, the outside variable contains max or min.

Examples in pseudocode:

```
int max = firstOfList
for (int i in set) { 
   if (i > max)
      max = i
}

int min = firstOfList
for (int i in set) { 
   if (i < min)
      min = i
}
```

As for the average you just add all the numbers and divide them by the size of the list.

To display all the numbers, again, you iterate and print them to the console.

PS: I ignored the easy way of just pointing out min/max functions, because you wanted to practice to program.

Comment: I'd like to point out the quality of this answer, well done sir.

Comment: Thanks guys! I started reading up on this a bit more now and all of this was really helpful. I found the 'easy' way of doing it also. :) I'm gonna keep coding a bit now and let you know when I get stuck again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
nr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=int(input("Please Enter an integer. "))
    nr.append(a)
s=[max(nr),min(nr),nr,sum(nr)/len(nr)]
z = int((input("Please a number ,1>max,2>min,3>full list,4>average"))) 
if z == 1:
    print ("max= ",s[0])
elif z== 2: 
    print ("Min= ",s[1] )
elif z == 3: 
    print ("full list== ", s[2])
elif z == 4:
     print ("average ",s[3]) 
else: 
    print('plz select number b/w:1 to 4')
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Yeah I've been playing around with the built-in functions. Where I'm stuck now is on how to get the program to let the user choose what they want to see. For example "Press 1 to see the biggest nr.", and so on.

Comment: nr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=int(input("Please Enter an integer. "))
    nr.append(a)
s=[max(nr),min(nr),nr,sum(nr)/len(nr)]
z = int((input("Please a number. ")) )
if z==1:
    print s[0]
elif z== 2:
    print s[0]
elif z == 3:
    print s[0]
elif z == 4:
    print s[0]
else:
    print('plz select number b/w:1 to 4')   try this

Comment: When i enter that code, what I get is: "Please enter an Integer.", and then then after that "please enter a number between 1 to 4."

Comment: I'm having trouble writing out the code in the right format here. It just becomes a long mess...

Answer (score 0):

Ok! It took a few hours but I finally solved it with the help from people on this forum. I'll share the code here if anyone would be interested. Thanks for all the help people!

```
nr=[]
for i in range(10):
a=int(input("Please enter an integer. "))
nr.append(a)
s = [max(nr), min(nr), nr, sum(nr)/len(nr)]
while 1:
    print("""What would you like to do now?:
        1. Show me the biggest integer.
        2. Show me the smallest integer.
        3. Show me the average of all the integers with one decimal.
        4. Show all the integers.
        5. Terminate this program.""")

    z = input("Choose a number between 1-5. ")
    if z == "1":
        print(s[0])
    elif z == "2":
        print(s[1])
    elif z == "3":
        print(s[3])
    elif z == "4":
        print(s[2])
    elif z == "5":
        break
    else:
        print("Please select a number between 1-5.")
```